# ¿Como añadir un JsonArray o arreglo como parametro a un petición hecha con Volley?

Tags: android, android-volley

Quisiera saber como añadir esto a un petición PATCH hecha en volley:

```
[
    {
        "op":"replace",
        "path":"/Clave1",
        "value":"5457184a-6951-4702-9ff6-5f2cfb8d7d71"

    },
    {
        "op":"replace",
        "path":"/Clave2",
        "value":"2017-09-13T10:58:24"

    }
]
```

se que se puede hacer algo como :

```
{ 
  "variable1":[
        {
            "op":"replace",
            "path":"/VaccineId",
            "value":"5457184a-6951-4702-9ff6-5f2cfb8d7d71"

        },
        {
            "op":"replace",
            "path":"/Date",
            "value":"2017-09-13T10:58:24"

        }
    ]
}
```

pero este ultimo ejemplo no me sirve tiene que ser como el primer código que coloque

Comment: Antes que nada, estas seguro que tu petición funciona enviando el JSONArray en lugar del JSONObject ?